# Can I create own literal types on .NET (F#)

Tags: f#, types, literals

for example if I want literal type for Nullable(x) like a

```
let x = 6x // nullable literal type
```

So is it real to make own literal types ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes, you can

F# spec:

Integer literals with the suffixes Q, R, Z, I, N, G are used for user-defined and library-defined types through the following syntactic translation:
**xxxx<suffix>**

- For xxxx = 0 - NumericLiteral.FromZero()
- For xxxx = 1 - NumericLiteral.FromOne()
- For xxxx in the Int32 range - NumericLiteral.FromInt32(xxxx)
- For xxxx in the Int64 range - NumericLiteral.FromInt64(xxxx)
- For other numbers - NumericLiteral.FromString("xxxx")

For example, defining a module NumericLiteralZ as below permits the use of the literal form 32Z to generate a sequence of 32 'Z' characters. No literal syntax is available for numbers outside the range of 32-bit integers.

```
module NumericLiteralZ =
    let FromZero() = ""
    let FromOne() = "Z"
    let FromInt32 n = String.replicate n "Z"

// nullables
open System
module NumericLiteralN = 
    let FromZero()          = Nullable(0)
    let FromOne()           = Nullable(1)
    let FromInt32(i : int)  = Nullable(i)

printfn "%A" 0N
printfn "%A" 1N
printfn "%A" 100N.HasValue
```

Comment: Just a small recommendation: don't use the N suffix, because it is used for rational numbers in the F# powerpack.

Comment: This should be added to Tomas Petricek's snippet pages.